# How to change soap version in php iis?

Tags: php, iis, soap

How to change soap version 1_2 from 1_1 on IIS Server php 5.6 ?

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Could not find any usable binding services in WSDL.

```
class GameService {

    public static $options = array(
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
        'exceptions'=>true, 
        'trace'=>1,
        'cache_wsdl'=> 0        
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP version is controlled by PHP and not IIS.  Change the line:

```
'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
```

to:

```
'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,
```

The [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php) provides a few more examples.